# Where context do modal events "live" in the UI?

Tags: python

I am trying to set up a set of shortcuts that trigger a few custom operations I've written in Python.

Do I need to invoke the modal in each area of the UI or do shortcuts work (i.e. get captured by the modal) regardless of which area is active (which - as far as I understand - equals the area where the mouse is currently hovering)?

I have a vague recollection of reading somewhere that events are global to all windows (while operators will or won't work depending on the context polled).

Also - testing code things show that if I invoke the modal multiple times, once for each context, shortcut events will trigger multiple times too.

Do I get it right? and are there sort of best practices on how to set up shortcuts vis-a-vis areas and modals? and documentation?